# Multiline statement with (hash) helper

Tags: ember.js, emblem.js

Since Ember launched [component block params](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.6.0/components/wrapping-content-in-a-component/) and contextual components you can pass multiple components back to the context for more control.

In handlebars you can write this inside your component template:

```
{{yield (hash
  header=(component modal-header)
  footer=(component modal-footer)
)}}
```

However when I try to achieve this in Emblem nothing seems to work.
I've tried using `[` and `]` but this doesn't seem to work in combination with the `hash` helper.

Can anyone help about the right syntax in this case?

Comment: My suggestion is to not use Emblem ;X Since it's not a project managed by the Ember team it has a tendency to fall behind on features.